# How to resize a pixmap with XLib?

Tags: c, linux, xlib

I'm using a pixmap as a window's backup in order to restore it under expose events. When the window is resized, must I resize the backup pixmap?

If so, what is the best way? Create a new pixmap with the new size?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you are right.

If the window is resized to a smaller size you just clip it.

If the window is bigger you allocate again to the new size.

My advice would also be to look at

- [xcb](http://xcb.freedesktop.org/) which replaces xlib at the moment
- [xshm](http://www.xfree86.org/current/mit-shm.html) functions for faster performance
- Xrender/[cairo](http://cairographics.org/)/[clutter](http://www.clutter-project.org/) that may do what you want already