# StretchBlt for Xlib?

Tags: gdi, x11, xlib

I'm looking for a function that does the same thing as GDI's StretchBlt for Xlib.  I can't find any such function in the XLib headers so I am beginning to think I will have to understand how StretchBlt works to implement it myself for XLib.  I appreciate any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resize a pixmap with XLib?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222631/how-to-resize-a-pixmap-with-xlib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing that does this in Xlib or the X protocol. Some ways to do it could include:

- gdk_pixbuf_composite() in gdk-pixbuf (part of GTK+ 2.x, separate lib for GTK+ 3.x)
- Cairo ( http://cairographics.org)
- OpenGL
- Skia ( http://code.google.com/p/skia/)
- write your own routine by hand

The best approach depends a lot on the details of your project. In general, Xlib's drawing primitives are nearly worthless by modern standards, so you really should get some higher layer library involved. Cairo is probably the default choice, it's widely-used in open source stuff.

Coding this yourself in a general and correct way for Xlib is pretty hard... the issue is that you have to deal with any visual and colormap your users might have. If you know the exact hardware and software your users will use, this may be a minor thing, otherwise it may be kind of a major headache.  There are a lot of conversions to write between 16-bit and 24-bit and 32-bit depths and different endianness and whatever. GTK+ and Cairo have conversion code in there, so if you can use them you can write a stretch routine in a fixed format such as ARGB32, and not have to deal with all the others.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of functionality is offered by the XRender extension:
http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/renderproto/plain/renderproto.txt