# Xlib: resize window containing a pixmap

Tags: c, xlib, x-dwm

Related to [how-to-resize-a-pixmap-with-xlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222631/how-to-resize-a-pixmap-with-xlib).
As it was concluded in the abovementioned topic, it's impossible to resize a pixmap. What about window, after pixmap is copied into it? In the example below, everything is good up to the point where the window is being resized. The icon is drawn after it's copied into the window, but is lost after the window is resized. Am I missing something here or there really is no way whatsoever to resize pixmap content?
Context: trying to add the client icons into the tabs for the [dwm](http://dwm.suckless.org/)'s [tab patch.](http://dwm.suckless.org/patches/tab)

```
unsigned int px_w, px_h, dummy_i;
Window icon_w, dummy_w;

Pixmap getWindowIcon (Window *w) {
    XWMHints *wmh;
    Pixmap pxmp = NULL;

    if(wmh = XGetWMHints(dpy, w)) {
        pxmp = wmh->icon_pixmap;
        XFree(wmh);
    }

    return pxmp;
}

Pixmap client_icon = getWindowIcon(current_window); // current_window is already existing Window instance
// find the pixmap dimensions and store in px_w, px_h:
XGetGeometry(dpy, client_icon, &dummy_w, &dummy_i, &dummy_i, &px_w, &px_h, &dummy_i, &dummy_i );

icon_w = XCreateSimpleWindow(dpy, root_window, 0, 0, px_w, px_h, 0, 0, color);
XMapRaised(dpy, icon_w);

// copy pixmap to the newly created win:
XCopyArea(dpy, client_icon, icon_w, cellDC.gc, 0, 0, px_w, px_h, 0, 0);

// resize - after which the pixmap is lost in the window:
XResizeWindow(dpy, icon_w, px_w+1, px_h+1);
```